# How can I convert an XML date to a valid datetime?

Tags: datetime, delphi

My program reads an XML file and extracts any date it can find. After a date was found, it uploads it to a database, but I can't figure out how I could convert an XML string (date) into a valid SQL datetime.

My XML date format:

`2021-08-26T00:25:26.737185Z`

Comment: What can't you do? Are you telling that you don't know how to parse a string to extract numbers and combine those numbers to build a datetime? Look at the functions `pos`, `SplitString`, `EncodeDate` and `EncodeTime`.

Comment: It's not an "XML date", it's a date in ISO 8601 format. See [`ISO8601ToDate()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.DateUtils.ISO8601ToDate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date looks like it is a date in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. In newer versions of Delphi, there is a function called [ISO8601ToDate](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.DateUtils.ISO8601ToDate) in System.DateUtils that converts a string in that format to a DateTime value:

```
USES System.DateUtils;
.
.
VAR S : STRING;
VAR DT : TDateTime;
.
.
S:='2021-08-26T00:25:26.737185Z';
DT:=ISO8601ToDate(S);
.
.
```